# Checking Annotation overlap with other features using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, overlapping-features

I want to check annotation features overlap with any other feature and also have to give other overlapped feature list....please tell any method for this?

Now i am using buffer around selected annotation feature...but that selected annotation feature only come within buffer,,other features from different feature class not coming....

I am new to ArcGIS.

Comment: Did you tried using topology?Simply create a topology in ArcCatalog,add your feature classes to topology and add desired rule to it.After validating topology,you can get a statistics of error(features violence rule of topology) and a list of them.Add topology to map in ArcMap,and find these features while red topology symbols show where they are.